# Retrieving document ID in apache solr clustering results

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis

So I'm trying to cluster the solr search results using the Lingo clustering algorithm that comes with solr 6. It does the job but I need it to retrieve the  document IDs (the IDs are called P_ID here) with the clustering results. I've been working on this and haven't had any luck, any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is the solrconfig.xml file

```
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
              startup="lazy"
              enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:true}"
              class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
    <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
    <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
    <!-- Logical field to physical field mapping. -->
    <str name="carrot.url">P_ID</str>
    <str name="carrot.title">input</str> 
    <str name="carrot.snippet">input</str>

    <!-- Configure any other request handler parameters. We will cluster the
         top 100 search results so bump up the 'rows' parameter. -->
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
        input^1.4
       </str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="rows">100</str>
    <str name="fl">*</str>
  </lst>
<arr name="last-components">
    <str>clustering</str>
  </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

And here's the results that I get:

{

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":24},
  "response":{"numFound":16,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "date":"2016-09-18 13:50:07.0",
        "input":"Text",
        "type":"q",
        "U_ID":2,
        "P_ID":1,
        "_version_":1548945773383647232},
      {
        "date":"2016-09-18 13:53:09.0",
        "input":"Text 2",
        "type":"q",
        "U_ID":10,
        "P_ID":2,
        "_version_":1548945773385744384},
      {
        "date":"2016-09-18 14:20:29.0",
        "input":"Text 3",
        "type":"q",
        "U_ID":12,
        "P_ID":3,
        "_version_":1548945773385744385},
      {
        "date":"2016-09-18 13:50:07.0",
        "input":"Text 4",
        "type":"q",
        "U_ID":3,
        "P_ID":4,
        "_version_":1548945773385744386},
      ]
  },
  "clusters":[{
      "labels":["label 1"],
      "score":6.723284893605449,
      "docs":["text ",
        "Text 2",
        "Text 4"
        ]},
    {
      "labels":["lable 2"],
      "score":10.22078770519469,
      "docs":["text 3",
        "Text 2"
        ]},
    {
      "labels":["label 3"],
      "score":8.32470981979922,
      "docs":["text 1",
        "text 3"
        ]},
    ]}
```

As you can see, under the "clusters" section it gives me the clusters and the documents but it doesn't give me the document IDs, I even tried changing the fl parameter to P_ID (document Id) but it didn't work. It can even show the P_ID values in the response section but not in the clusters section.

Comment: What is the uniqueKey setting of your schema? If I understand the docs correctly, the clustering component will use that field as the field returned in the docs array.

Comment: The unique key is the P_ID (P_ID is document ID here) and this is already specified in the scheme, but I don't understand why rather than returning the P_IDs, the clustering returns the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So I came up with a solution that satisfies what I needed. All I needed to do  was to put the document ID in the `<uniqueKey></uniqueKey>` element in the schema.